# Don't show me questions in the HIQ that I have flagged

Tags: feature-request, bug, help-improvement

While going through the HIQ (Help and Improvement Queue) earlier today, I flagged about 10 questions as Very Low Quality. Most these ended up getting disputed (because they passed triage as Looks Ok or Should be Improved instead of being marked Unsalvageable).

I then entered the HIQ again, and found many of these same questions to review again that I already flagged as VLQ. It was annoying. I think if I flag them as VLQ again, it doesn't work, and rightfully so. So my only option is to skip since I'm not going to edit a VLQ question that should be closed right away. I ended up just ramming the Skip button many times and then left the queue since it was annoying to keep seeing the same VLQ questions come up for me to act on.

But really, I don't think it'd matter whether I flagged as Spam, Offensive, or any other reason besides VLQ. So my feature request is to not show me any question in HIQ that I've already flagged for any reason.

Comment: I haven't been doing many reviews in HIQ as of late. So haven't tested if this was ever fixed or not. Guessing not since no status-completed. But please comment if you notice this bug at all too.

Comment: Is this really a designed/wanted behaviour? Firstly it seems that 80% of stuff in HIQ is not something that can be bettered by editing by anyone other than OP - so should not be marked as _Requires editing_?. And when you flag then LQ they just pop up again and again.Yes, annoying.