# Help and Improvement queue skipped questions appearing again

Tags: bug, review-queues, questions, help-improvement

As everyone can see - Help and Improvement queue often contains questions which really can't be improved by someone other than the author.

Well, we have "Skip" button, and it pretty much does its job - just skips such a question and retrieves next one from queue.

But few days ago I've started to see questions which were already skipped by me appearing in my queue again.

For example, today morning I've seen this question:
[Can we capture a mobile number through a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840873/can-we-capture-mobile-number-throught-mobile-website-in-php-or-net-web-applicat),

I skipped it, but after half of hour (or something like) I've seen this question again in the queue.

Is it some queue bug or intended behavior?

For me it's hard to imagine situation when I've decided "I can't improve anything in this question", but in some short amount of time I've changed my mind and found things to improve in the same question.

Comment: Yeah, I've got that a few times as well.

Comment: This is not intended behavior. Skipping a review should always mean that you don't receive that review again. Except for maybe cases in which a post was brought back into a queue for the second time. But not sure why that would happen for HIQ or what's going on here.  Somewhat related question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289770/dont-show-me-questions-in-the-hiq-that-i-have-flagged)

Comment: @Roombatron5000 maybe people in HIQ flag as VLQ but triage just sends it back again?