# Help and Improvement queue show skipped question over and over

Tags: bug, review-queues, questions, help-improvement

This question is already asked here: [Help and Improvement queue skipped questions appearing again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291326/5779732). That question was asked in Apr-2015. There are no answers to that question yet. The bug is neither confirmed/rejected nor fixed.

I have nothing more to say. If someone post an answer there, this question could be marked as duplicate or I will delete this.

Comment: This may be because the queues (other than the close vote one, of course) have been relatively sparse as of late, so when there are no other posts left in it for you to review, it cycles back around to things you've skipped. Whether that's a bug or by design is debatable.

Comment: Obviously that question has been skipped over and over.

Comment: As far as I recollect, in case of documentation review, the skipped question never reappeared in the reviews. It would simply show "No further pending reviews" if I had skipped all pending reviews.

Comment: This is a problem that needs to be addressed. I have encountered the same item 4 times now, I skipped it two times, got annoyed of it the third time and flagged it as VLQ (which it really is, imo) and now I got it a fourth time. I flagged it again as VLQ (interestingly enough both flags don't show up in my history?). What else can I do? I don't know how else to handle this specific item... imo, it shouldn't be shown to me again after the first skip. If I didn't know how to handle it an hour ago, chances are slim that I know how to handle it now.